# Using FileWriter in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, streamwriter

I am trying to write some text at the end of the file.

Here is my code

```
Dim Writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText("D:\Vishal.txt")
Writer.WriteLine("I am Vishal")
```

But I am not getting anything in the above mentioned file.
Also there are no errors in the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to flush the stream to write it's buffer, you could call [`writer.Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx), `writer.Close` or use the `using`-statement what is best practise anyway when using disposable objects:

```
Using Writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText("D:\Vishal.txt")
    Writer.WriteLine("I am Vishal")
End Using
```

That works because a `StreamWriter` gets closed implicitely before it's disposed.